# Active Record Query with order and where from different tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I have the following models:

```
  class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    delegate :workspace, :to => :project, :allow_nil => true
    belongs_to :importance
    belongs_to :urgency
  end

  class Urgency < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tasks
  end

  class Importance < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tasks
  end
```

I am trying to display information in the view which shows a table of all of the Tasks which have high Urgency and high Importance and ordered by workspace.

In the controller, I have the following code:

```
    @task_high_priority = Task.joins(:project => :workspace).order("workspaces.workspace_name").where(urgency_id: 1).where(importance_id: 1)
```

What I want to do is have the where condition in the query look at another column in the urgency and importance models (urgency_value and importance_value respectively).

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Task.joins(:project => :workspace)
  .joins(:importance)
  .joins(:urgency)
  .where(urgency: {urgency_value: 'high'})
  .where(importance: {importance_value: 'high'})
  .order("workspaces.workspace_name")
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm receiving the following error:  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: urgency.urgency_value: SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "tasks"."project_id" INNER JOIN "workspaces" ON "workspaces"."id" = "projects"."workspace_id" INNER JOIN "importances" ON "importances"."id" = "tasks"."importance_id" INNER JOIN "urgencies" ON "urgencies"."id" = "tasks"."urgency_id" WHERE "urgency"."urgency_value" = ? AND "importance"."importance_value" = ? ORDER BY workspaces.workspace_name

Comment: That means you need to use the correct column name from your urgency table

Comment: I've tried it again and the code works when I pluralise:           .where(urgencies: {urgency_value: 'high'})
  .where(importances: {importance_value: 'high'})